# How to filter data from API , ListView - React-Native

Tags: listview, react-native, searchbar

i'm trying to filter data with React-Native but the info in Stackoverflow doesn't help so much.

What i have:

[ArtistListView File](https://pastebin.com/CH5TMRW3)

I have a api-client.js file:

```
const URL = 'API_URL';

function getArtists(){
return fetch(URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data.topartists.artist)
    .then(artists =>artists.map(artist => {
        return {
            id: artist.mbid,
            name: artist.name,
            image: artist.image[3]['#text'],
            url: artist.url,
            likes: 400,
            comments: 200,
        }
    }))

  }

  export{ getArtists }
```

but i got the error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.artist.toUpperCase')

hope that anyone can explain to me what i have wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i already solve it, i must change the props to state... In my [Github repo](https://github.com/fabianchoxD/FsvMusic_React_Native)  can found the complete code.